# Adding Auto-Activation Characters for an Eclipse Content Assist Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-plugin, content-assist

I've implemented a content assist proposal computer as an eclipse plugin (using `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalComputer`) and it internally uses a `IContentAssistProcessor`. The Processor class provides a method for specifying auto-activation characters for the content assist menu, called `getCompletionProposalAutoActivationCharacters()`. However, since I'm only using this class internally, it is not registered with the workbench in any way and the auto-activation characters I defined are not actually activating the content assist menu.

Is there a way to "register" my `IContentAssistProcessor` class so that the `getCompletionProposalAutoActivationCharacters()` method will get called?

Is there another way to associate a `javaCompletionProposalComputer` class with auto-activation characters (defined by the plugin, and not manually in the workbench)?